# BinaryReader on MemoryStream stay empty

Tags: .net, vb.net, tcp, stream, binary

```
            SyncLock _client.GetStream
                Dim bArray() As Byte
                Dim bWriter As New BinaryWriter(_client.GetStream)

                Dim bf As New BinaryFormatter
                Dim mStream As New MemoryStream

                bf.Serialize(mStream, dSet)

                'Send tagIdentifier
                bWriter.Write(bTag)
                'Send the Object length
                bWriter.Write(CInt(mStream.ToArray.Length))

                'It's not null, value of 3024
                Console.WriteLine("Mstream : " & mStream.ToArray.Length)

                'Initialize the BinaryReader
                Dim bReader As New BinaryReader(mStream)
                Do
                    bArray = bReader.ReadBytes(1024)
                    ''''''''''''''bArray stay at 0'''''''''''''''
                    bWriter.Write(bArray)
                Loop While bArray.Length = 1024

                bWriter.Flush()
            End SyncLock
```

So I have this code, what I'm trying to do is sending a serialized dataset.

So I put the serialized dSet in a memoryStream and transform it to an array of byte to send it with the BinaryWritter

Also, the BinaryReader pointer seems to stay at 0 even if the mSteam have a value of 3024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just wrote to the MemoryStream, the pointer is at the end where there is nothing to read.  Reset the position back to 0 (zero) before attempting to read from it:

```
    mStream.Position = 0
```

Comment: Was it specified somewhere that the cursor postion stay at the end, or I,m supposed to know it ?

Comment: I would just call that "general knowledge".  In general, the position in a stream is directly after where ever you last wrote it, unless you explicitly change said position (or close and open the stream again).